# How to change select value to a specific value when a ckeckbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is the tiny setup. Assume, the standard value of **Color** and **Model** is `green` and `v1` respectively.

The main concept is, when I check the the `Select all to standard` checkbox, all the select drop down should be changed to their standard value (`green` and `v1`).

And if I select anything other than standard, like `red` and `v1` (one of them in not standard) or, `red` and `v2` (both of them are not standard), the check will automatically be on the `Custom` checkbox.

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Here is the snippet:

```js
$(function(){
$("#standard").change(function() {
    var item = this.checked ? "green" : "";
    $("#color").val(item);
    var item = this.checked ? "v1" : "";
    $("#model").val(item);
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-3'>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" id="standard">Select all to standard<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">Custom<br>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Color</label>
      <select id="color" name="color" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Select one</option>
         <option value="red">Red</option>
         <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Model</label>
      <select id="model" name="model" class="form-control">
         <option value="">Select one</option>
         <option value="v1">Version 1</option>
         <option value="v2">Version 2</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript you tried?

Comment: It feels like those checkboxes should be radio buttons instead.

Comment: @j08691, I'm sorry I haven't added it in the first place what I've tried. I was not sure weather I were doing it the right way or not. I've updated what I've tried. I couldn't figure out the `Custom` part. And also not sure if it is the best way how I am doing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JosephMarikle for the suggestion, but I need checkbox here because of some additional operations I intend to perform with it in the real page. So, I guess I have to keep the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this to achieve your goal. If you need something more, comment here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Trst</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>  
</head>
<body>
<div class='col-sm-3'>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="standard" class="selectOptions">Select all to standard<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="custom" class="selectOptions">Custom<br>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Color</label>
   <select id="color" name="color" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select one</option>
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
   </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Model</label>
   <select id="model" name="model" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select one</option>
   <option value="v1">Version 1</option>
   <option value="v2">Version 2</option>
   </select>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
 $(".selectOptions").click(function() {
  if( $(this).attr('id') === "standard" ){
   $("#custom").prop('checked', false);
   $("select#color").val("green");
   $("select#model").val("v1");
  }else{
   $("#custom").prop('checked', true);
   $("#standard").prop('checked', false);
  }  
 });
 
 $("select").change(function() {
  if( this.value !== "green" || this.value !== "v1" ){
   $("#custom").prop('checked', true);
   $("#standard").prop('checked', false);
  } 
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your suggestion. I really appreciate the effort. I think this is well enough for all I need for now.  :)

Comment: Hi @fatih, can I ask you for a favor? I have been trying to implement it one my page, but for some reason, it it not working outside stackoverflow. This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/3nt1n9a5/) link of your version. Can you help me with a fiddle link of your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Ashonko use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1waywalker/7v821y5L/) link. Also I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again. Can you explain me if you don't mind why it didn't work the last time? I'm just curious to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Have some suggestion like use radio box rather than checkbox and change the UI with CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class='col-sm-3'>
<input type="radio" name="check_value" id="standard" class="checkbox_event" value="all">Select all to standard<br>
<input type="radio" name="check_value" id="custom_box" class="checkbox_event" value="custom">Custom<br>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-3'>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Color</label>
  <select id="color" name="color" class="select_list form-control">
     <option value="">Select one</option>
     <option value="red">Red</option>
     <option value="green">Green</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Model</label>
  <select id="model" name="model" class="form-control select_list">
     <option value="">Select one</option>
     <option value="v1">Version 1</option>
     <option value="v2">Version 2</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){

    var my_array = new Array('v2','red');

    $("#standard").change(function() {
        var item = this.checked ? "green" : "";
        $("#color").val(item);
        var item = this.checked ? "v1" : "";
        $("#model").val(item);
    });


    $(".select_list").change(function(e) {
        if( ($.inArray($('#color').val(), my_array) == -1) && ($.inArray($('#model').val(), my_array)  == -1 )){
            $('#custom_box').prop('checked',false);
            $('#standard').prop('checked',true);
        }else if( ($.inArray($('#color').val(), my_array) == -1) || ($.inArray($('#model').val(), my_array)  == -1 )){
            $('#custom_box').prop('checked',true);
            $('#standard').prop('checked',false);
        }else{
            $('#custom_box').prop('checked',false);
            $('#standard').prop('checked',true);
        }
    });

 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @waseem for the suggestion, but I need checkbox here because of some additional operations I intend to perform with it in the real page. So, I guess I have to keep the checkbox. Thanks anyway for your effort on this suggestion.  :)